# How to add a second touchPoint in TouchesBegan Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a `touchesMoved` function for three `UIImageView`s, I want to add a function that lets me use more than one touchPoint to move the `UIImageView`s but I'm not quite sure how to do that, a little help would be awesome.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var attachment: UIAttachmentBehavior?
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

@IBOutlet var Ball3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Ball2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Ball1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Floor: UIImageView!


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch2 = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    location = touch2.locationInView(self.view)

    if CGRectContainsPoint(Ball1.frame,location)
    {
        attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: Ball1, attachedToAnchor: location)
        animator!.addBehavior(attachment!)
    }

    if CGRectContainsPoint(Ball2.frame,location)
    {
        attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: Ball2, attachedToAnchor: location)
        animator!.addBehavior(attachment!)
    }

    if CGRectContainsPoint(Ball3.frame,location)
    {
        attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: Ball3, attachedToAnchor: location)
        animator!.addBehavior(attachment!)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch2 = touches.first as UITouch!
    location = touch2.locationInView(self.view)
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    if attachment != nil
    {
        attachment!.anchorPoint = location
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if animator != nil && attachment != nil
    {
        self.attachment == nil
        animator!.removeBehavior(self.attachment!)
    }
}
```

Comment: well, if you use `first` both times you will get the first element both times - no two different locations.

Comment: I am new to coding, what would I do to make it work?

Comment: By not using `first` but instead getting a different object out of the `Set` - google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give each ball a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/), then they will operate independently. Given a gesture recognizer, you can use its `locationInView(_:)` or `translationInView(_:)` methods to get the offset (and the `view` property to get the view that it's attached to).

I would recommend reading the [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW7).